# Variable is not defined - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to ask, on why the variable `title` is getting an undefined error even though there's a value on it. Here's my code so far:

```
   <div class="echelon-main-container" id="test-app">
        <test-empower></test-empower>
        <script type="x-template" id="test-empower">
            <section class="test-empower" id="test-empower">
                <h2 class="header-title">{{ title }}</h2>
                <h2 class="header-subtitle">{{ description }}</h2>
            </section>
        </script>
    </div>

Vue.component('echelon-empower', {
    template: '#echelon-empower',
    data: function() {
        return {
            title: "AT ECHELON",
            description: "Empowering Entrepreneurs to build and grow their companies since 2009"
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('echelon-about', {
    template: '#echelon-about'
});

Vue.component('echelon-who-attends',{
    template: '#echelon-who-attends'
});

Vue.component('echelon-highlights', {
    template: '#echelon-highlights'
});

new Vue({
    el: "#echelon-app"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The below `html` which has an `id` of `#test-app` derives its `vue-instance` properties from the `new Vue(...)` part of the code. Which really doesn't have `title` and hence the error.

   ```
   <div class="echelon-main-container" id="test-app">
       <test-empower></test-empower>
       <script type="x-template" id="test-empower">
           <section class="test-empower" id="test-empower">
               <h2 class="header-title">{{ title }}</h2>
               <h2 class="header-subtitle">{{ description }}</h2>
           </section>
       </script>
   </div>
   ```
2. The `el` property in the `new Vue(...)` specifies the `mount` point for the `new Vue()` instance you are creating.
3. In the `Vue.component(...)`:

   ```
   Vue.component('test-empower', {
     template: '#test-empower'
   });
   ```

   `#test-empower` is not the mount point as you are expecting. It is the template this component must use when `<test-empower>` is used in your application.

---

As per the edit, you need to separate out your templates to resolve your need of having separate properties like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2gsunft/).

Comment: So the title will be duplicated. because I already added it in `Vue.Component` and you  say I need to add also in `new Vue`

Comment: Unless you need the `title` in the `test-empower` component you can remove it from the `vue.component`. Also, I am editing my answer to make it more descriptive. :)

Comment: I edited my question. Actually that's why I don't want to put the `title` variable in `new Vue` because i have multiple `Vue.Component` that will be used inside the .html so in that case I may have multiple `title` per `Vue.Component`

Comment: Okay, so you wish to use different templates for each component? can I ask you about your development platform?

Comment: I just use Vuejs on some views of our web application. it is built on PHP,

Comment: @SydneyLoteria Check the fiddle in the answer, I think it would be of use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139758/discussion-between-sydney-loteria-and-amresh-venugopal).